# reading/writing xmp metadatas on pdf files through pypdf

Tags: python, pdf, metadata, xmp, pypdf

I can read xmp metadatas through pypdf with this code:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

a = PdfReader("file.pdf")
b = a.xmp_metadata
c = b.pdf_keywords
```

But is this the best way?

And if I don't use the pdf_keywords property?

Is there any way to set these metadatas with pypdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is the best way to do so - and there is no way to change the metadata with pyPDF.